# undefined local variable or method `last_email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, actionmailer

I'm following the [#275 Railscasts of Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test), but I can't make the tests pass, because of the `last_email` method.

Here is the test : **spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb**

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

subject { page }

describe "Password reset for a registered user" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }  
  before do
    visit new_password_reset_path
    fill_in t('user.email'), with: user.email
    click_button(t('submit.reset.password'))
  end

  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', t('flash.success.reset_password.sent')) }
  expect(last_email).to have_content(user.email)
end
```

And here the error message :

```rb
spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `last_email' for #<Class:0x000000063b18d8> (NameError
```

Here is the **new_password_reset** view :

```rb
<%= form_tag password_resets_path, :method => :post do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email, t('user.email') %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag t('submit.reset.password'), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And the **new_password_reset** controller `create` method :

```rb
def create 
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  user.send_password_reset if user
  flash[:success] = t('flash.success.reset_password.sent')
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

And just like in the railscast, I did the following :

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```rb
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include(MailerMacros)
  config.before(:each) { reset_email }
end
```

**spec/support/mailer_macros.rb**

```rb
module MailerMacros
  def last_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  end

  def reset_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're calling the `last_email` method at the class level rather than within a block.

You need `expect(last_email).to have_content(user.email)` to be defined with a `it` block i.e.

```
it "should show alert and dispatch email to the user" do
   page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', t('flash.success.reset_password.sent'))
   expect(last_email).to have_content(user.email)
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I had already added it, but I wanted to keep the code simple on Stackoverflow...

Comment: Yes I have the `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}` line in my `spec_helper.rb` file...

Comment: Change `expect(last_email).to have_content(user.email)` to `last_email.to.should include(user.email)` and tell me if you get any errors.

Comment: Always the same error, I began with it, and changed it afterwards to see if there was any change.